# Inject contacts in journey builder with specific criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I want to inject contacts into a Journey who meets specific criteria in SF. It seems that Salesforce Entry Data in JB doesn´t work for me because:

-Contacts created in Salesforce. I need to inject those who are already in SF

-Contacts updated in Salesforce. I have 10 attributes and not all of them will be updated so no contacts will be added to the journey.

I decided to trigger the journey with an automation through a populated DE to inject all those contacts I need to impact. However, after this I cannot filter the DE in Journey Builder, I can only filter through the Salesforce Data. Any suggestion of how to approach this case? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you filter using the query in the automation? This would be the best option I guess.

Comment: @Daniel can you post more info about your setup? The best thing, IMO would be to create an entry point from Salesforce Data, map out all of your fields then you can use decision splits throughout your journey. If data is continuously being updated and you need to check it, you may need to do some contact builder configuration. You may be able to use goals and exit criteria as well.

Comment: @garek007 my doubt is if each criteria within Salesforce Entry Data have to be updated in order to inject the contacts or just with one criteria that has been updated. Thanks!